# Converse opening a chat from API

Tags: javascript, converse.js

I'm looking into ways to open a chat window with a user via the API.

I have set up (and registered in the whitelist) a plugin, which triggers.

```
    converse.plugins.add('startChat', {
        initialize: function () {
            this._converse.on('connected', function () {
                console.log("wibble");
                this._converse.api.chats.open('user@chat.domain.com');
            });
          }
      });
```

This is firing, but no chat is initiated. I get the following errors in console:

```
wibble

converse.js:48049
FATAL: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at child.createChatBox (/converse.js:50015:56)
    at child.getChatBox (/converse.js:50050:40)
    at Object.open (/converse.js:50153:84)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Page.aspx:1264:41)
    at triggerEvents (/converse.js:46015:57)
    at triggerApi (/converse.js:46003:19)
    at eventsApi (/converse.js:45802:16)
    at Object.Events.trigger (/converse.js:45993:5)
    at Object._converse.emit (/converse.js:48071:27)
    at Object.onConnected (/converse.js:48671:27)

converse.js:48041 
ERROR: User connection callback caused an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Converse.js doesn't allow opening chats with users who aren't in your roster (unless you have set [allow_non_roster_messaging](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#allow-non-roster-messaging) to `true`). So make sure the user you're trying to chat with is in your roster.

Secondly, right after the `connection` event has been fired is still too early to try and open chats.

So you have to first wait until the roster has been populated. This is the [rosterContactsFetched](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/events.html#rostercontactsfetched) event/promise.

Besides that, it's a good idea to also first wait until already opened chat boxes (which are cached in sessionStorage) have also been fetched from the cache. This is the [chatBoxesFetched](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/events.html#chatboxesfetched) event/promise.

These two events fire only once per session, so they're also available as promises.

To first wait for these two promises to resolve, you're code would therefore look like this:

```
converse.plugins.add('startChat', {
  initialize: function() {
    var _converse = this._converse;
    Promise.all([
        _converse.api.waitUntil('rosterContactsFetched'),
        _converse.api.waitUntil('chatBoxesFetched')
    ]).then(function() {
      // Note, test@conversejs.org must be in your contacts roster!
      _converse.api.chats.open('test@conversejs.org');
    });
  } 
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle which runs the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/jcbrand/5juvrL3c/

Comment: Ah - the not opening chats with users not in my roster was the missing link for me.

Comment: This is not working for me... converse refuses to open a chat window

Answer (score 0):

And for future travellers: I solved starting a converse chat from outside converse like so:

```
<li id="start-chat" data-id="idOfTheUser" data-name="nameOfTheUser"> Message</li>
```

Then a plugin like so:

```
    converse.plugins.add('startChat', {
        initialize: function () {
            var _converse = this._converse;

            $('#start-chat').on('click', function () {

                var jid = $('#start-chat').attr("data-id") +'@chat.domain.com';
                var userFullName = $('#start-chat').attr("data-name");

                _converse.api.contacts.add(jid, userFullName);
                _converse.api.chats.open(jid, true);
            });
          }
      });
```